# Limits and Boundaries of SharePoint Online for Bulk operations

Tags: sharepoint-online, bulk, insert-update-listitem

Just want to know what is the Limits and Boundaries of SharePoint Online for Bulk operations. Is there any authentic document I can refer? I am trying to insert 20,000 items with 5 text fields in a batch of 100. sometimes it throws Error "The Operation has timed out" I am using jquery + rest api to perform this bulk operation

Comment: Are you doing this by physically copy and pasting into the list, or are you scripting this?

Comment: I am using JSOM Script

Answer (score 2):

This does not give you the limits but maybe a solution for your problem.

The bulk limits for SharePoint 2013 is 100 items per operation so i guess it is around that number in Online aswell. [SharePoint 2013 Software boundaries](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits)

[image]

But to resolve your problem try extending the RequestTimeout for your context.

[MSDN article explaining RequestTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee541007.aspx).

But as you are using jQuery and the rest api try setting the timeout property on the ajax call. [jQuery ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: will try it and revert about the results

Comment: This is the correct answer.  You need to reset the browser threads which are causing the timeout on the browser.  Use the setTimeout(function(){}, 100); to break up the upload.  I would also put some type of modal wait function to lock the page because it will take some time to load everything.

Comment: @VikasSharma did you have any success trying out my suggested answer? Also I have updated my answer with a bit more information.

Comment: For Jquery it did not work.  Tried time out function but sometimes it gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing real bulk requests, or do you make a request per item?

If it is the later, try to schedule your requests and give SP some time. I don't think there are official hard numbers, since there are a lot of relevant factors that are not limited to the service for a timeout to occur.

Had the same problem with general CRUD operations. I would suggest to leave some time between any two requests and don't bulk transfer anything.

(real bulk (batch) requests are possible and shouldn't have this problem. They are available in newer SP installations, but I don't know about their limits. Didn't find a lot of documentation, although that might have been improved.)

Comment: I agreed with your answer. I didn't understand the meaning of real bulk batch ? What do you mean by this ? Synchronous code?

Comment: The "normal" rest operation targets just a single item with a specific itemID. So to update a list with n items, you would have to send n requests. A single bulk request would allow you to create, update or delete n items within a single request. That has the advantage, that there are no further timeouts required. All the payload of the operations for many items is contained in that single request.